# DB2 SQL XMLSERIALIZE / XML value of Select *

Tags: sql, xml, db2, xmlelement

I would like to output all fields of a SELECT SQL in DB2 as XML. Sorry for using "Select *" here but in this case it makes sense.
Have checked XMLSERIALIZE and XMLELEMENT commands but they need a field list.
e.g.

`SELECT  XMLELEMENT (*) as X from DATA1.CUSTOMERS where CUSTOMERNO='262627'`

or

```
SELECT  XMLSERIALIZE (*) as X from DATA1.CUSTOMERS where CUSTOMERNO='262627'
```

does not work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no XML publishing function that accepts the wildcard. The easiest way would be to use [XMLROW](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050587.html). It accepts a column list or more complex expressions and gives you some options for the final format.

```
select xmlrow(col1, col2) from mytable
```

or

```
select xmlrow(col1, col2 option row "myrowname") from mytable
```